# Under what assumptions can parameter estimate uncertainty be estimated from the Hessian?

Tags: optimization, uncertainty, parameterization

Given a model with some parameters, some data it's attempting to reproduce, and a distance function to quantify how well the predictions correspond to the data, I can fit parameters via a general purpose optimisation routine such as R's `optim`. To what extent is it possible to say anything about the reliability of such estimates without taking into account the specifics of the model, or the data, or the distance?

It seems like a common approach is to numerically estimate the Hessian at the optimum and use this to calculate standard errors, but doing so seems to be predicated on interpreting the minimised function as the likelihood. Is that a requirement? How about a transformation of the likelihood, or some proxy for it?

Suppose I blindly go ahead and calculate such "standard errors" anyway, what, if anything, do they tell me? What assumptions would be implied about the model?

Intuitively, it seems like one ought to be able to say something about the optimisation itself (parameter A is sharply peaked and converges precisely, parameter B is barely identifiable and could be out by orders of magnitude), but that there may be no scale against which to quantify this without additional assumptions about the model/data/distance.